# Multiple field with identical name in Spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired, entity-bean

I've got the following:

```
public class ClaimFacadeImpl implements ClaimFacade {

    @Autowired
    private DebtRepository<Claim> debtRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DebtRepository<Fine> fineRepository;

    //other stuff

}

public interface DebtRepository <T extends Debt> {
   //nothing special
}

public class DebtRepositoryImpl <T extends Debt> implements DebtRepository <T> {
   //nothing special
}
```

and 2 classes. One Claim and one Fine both extending Debt. 
I'm getting the error `More than one field with type interface domain.debt.DebtRepository`

what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to Spring 4.0 if you have not done it already:

See http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics